# Generate combinations with repeated symbols?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I would like to generate fixed size sequences contained a fixed number of repeated symbols.
For example how to generate sequences of size N containing exactly p symbols of one type q symbols of another, etc... where p, q, etc. < N.

In my case I want to generate sequences of size 13 containing 3 symbols denoted x, 2 symbols denoted y and 2 symbols denoted z.  Blank spaces are marked with '-'

So it would look like 
xxxyyzz------, 
x-xx--y-y-zz-
...
etc.

There are C(13, 3)*C(10,2)*C(8,2) ways of generating such sequences but I have no idea how to generate them.

Technically how do you describe this problem?  Combinations with repetitions?
Where can I find a description of algorithms to solve this? Does Knuth book describe this algorithms?  Most of the solutions I find deal with generating permutations or combinations but none deal with repeated elements.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this might be more for math.SE Consider multinomial coefficients:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem#Multinomial_coefficients

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. It led to me to the correct technical description of this problem which is the enumeration of permutations of a multiset. Now I need to find an algorithm to generate this permutations.

Comment: There is quite a literature on this. A google search on "permutations of a multiset generation" will give many hits.

Comment: E.g. see Knuth's _The Art of Computer Programming_ Volume 4A, section 7.2.1.2 "Generating all permutations". (This section was earlier published in Vol 4 Fasc 2, and before that as [pre-fascicle 2B](http://www.cs.utsa.edu/~wagner/knuth/fasc2b.pdf).) The very first page of this section (page 319) has an "Algorithm L" that should work quite nicely.